# Wireguard routing

Tags: networking, wireguard

I have setup a wireguard connection, but I have some problems with routing. I have two locations where wireguard computers establishing VPN are behind internet provider's routers. I can be at one or another location. That means that I need to have a remote access to the other site in order to setup the VPN. VPN was successfully established, and it broke. Since I cannot login to the remote location I cannot set it up again. I have to wait to get to another location. I cannot login to a distant location because of a problem described below.

I have setup a remote SSH access to these computers, so I can access them via internet, by entering NAT into routers. I login to router address and router forwards SSH to internal address, and SSH access works fine, but there is a catch.

As soon as I bring up `wg0` interface and try to establish VPN, SSH access does not work any more. I have analyzed the traffic, and the following happens. When I start SSH, router forwards it and wireguard computer receives `SYN` packet on `eth0` interface. However, `SYN, ACK` packet is not sent back via `eth0`, but via `wg0` interface, when `wg0` is active. Without `wg0` interface SSH work fine. SSH also works in local network `192.168.1.0/24` regardless of `wg0` interface.

How can keep my SSH connectivity and use wireguard VPN connection at the same time? I have another interface `lan0` on that computer, which is not connected right now. Should I connect `lan0` to intranet, too and use it for SSH? I guess the problem with wireguard would remain with `lan0` interface as it would be connected to same network as `eth0`.

Here is some additional information about connections, routes, etc.

**Without wg0 interface:**

`wg-quick down wg0` output:

```
[#] ip -4 rule delete table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] ip link delete dev wg0
[#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
```

ip -4 addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:b7:6b:c9:08:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.250/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 84256sec preferred_lft 84256sec
3: lan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:b7:6b:c9:08:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ip route:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.250 metric 100
```

ip rule:

```
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**With wg0 interface:**

`wg-quick up wg0` output:

```
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.0.0.2/24 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
```

ip -4 addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:b7:6b:c9:08:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.250/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 84320sec preferred_lft 84320sec
3: lan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group 
default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:b7:6b:c9:08:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.250 metric 100
```

ip rule:

```
0:  from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**Update:**
After some more testing, I found out that wg-quick sets up some ip routes and rules. I suspect that these are messing up the SSH connectivity. If I try the following commands SSH still works.

```
ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
ip address add dev wg0 10.0.0.2/24
wg set wg0 private-key /root/wgprivate.key
wg set wg0 listen-port 37723
ip link set wg0 up
wg set wg0 peer <key> allowed-ips 0.0.0.0/0 persistent-keepalive 25 endpoint <remote hostname>:<remote port>
```

Since I do not have access to the remote site until weekend, I will try to find out, which commands in wg-quick cause the erratic behaviour. When I will have access to the remote site, I will establish VPN again without wg-quick. I did that already before, but wanted to automate it with wg-quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that I do not want the routing that wg-quick makes after establishing the connection. So, the solution is pretty simple. Put a line

```
Table = off
```

in `[Interface]` section. That instructs wg-quick not to make ip rules and routes.

Answer (score 0):

have a look [here](https://www.system-rescue.org/networking/Destination-port-routing/), but let it boil down a bit to your problem:

You can use iptables to mark the packages to  the destination port 22

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 22
```

So you can insert a high priority rule to route these packages through eth0

```
ip rule add priority 32000 fwmark 22 table 22
ip route flush table 22
ip route add table 22 default dev eth0
```

Have not tested it, and a possible side effect could be that you are no longer able to connect port 22 via the VPN